# string to Currency format, with no periods (or commas)

Tags: c#, string

given value = 2 or 4.00

 the below statement outputs

```
value = Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString("C2");
```

value = $2.00, or $4.00

if I have value = 1000 then output will be `$1,000.00` but I require `$1000.00`.

I don't prefer string concatenation of "$" and value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var stringValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString("$0.00");
```

As noted by @James below, this hard-codes the currency into the format.  Using the format `C2` will use the system currency format.  This can be changed for the system (e.g. in Windows 7 - Start - Control Panel - Change Display Language - Additional Settings - Currency - Digit grouping) and will allow the `C2` format to display the currency value without the comma when running on that particular system.

**EDIT**

All credit to @James for using the current culture.  My only modification to his answer would be to clone the current `NumberFormat` so as to get all the properties of the current culture number format before removing the `CurrencyGroupSeparator`.

```
var formatInfo = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
formatInfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator = string.Empty;

var stringValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString("C", formatInfo);
```

Comment: Although it works, it's not a flexible solution i.e. your hardcoding the currency symbol to be dollars.

Comment: Is there a way to convert this stringValue back into the number?

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `NumberFormat` class to specify the type of formatting you need, `ToString` takes an `IFormatProvider` parameter e.g.

```
var formatInfo = (System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
formatInfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ""; // remove the group separator
Console.WriteLine(2.ToString("C", formatInfo));
Console.WriteLine(4.ToString("C", formatInfo));
Console.WriteLine(1000.ToString("C", formatInfo));
```

This will keep your number formatting consistent with whichever culture you are using.

Comment: Perhaps use `var formatInfo = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();` instead of creating a new `NumberFormatInfo`? that way you will ensure you have the full number format for the current culture.

Comment: @Kevin +1 yeah for completeness that would be a better solution overall. Will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string GetMoney(this decimal value, bool displayCurrency = false, bool displayPeriods = true)
    {
        string ret = string.Format("{0:C}", value).Substring(displayCurrency ? 0 : 1);
        if (!displayPeriods)
        {
            ret = ret.Replace(",", string.Empty);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

To use this extension method:

```
decimal test = 40023.2345M;
string myValue = test.GetMoney(displayCurrency:true, displayPeriods:false);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting the integer value into $0.00 format

int Value = 1000;
  string abc = Convert.ToDecimal(Value).ToString("$0.00");
output will  be $1000.00